# googletest - find out where unexpected call was made

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest, googlemock

I run some unit tests in googletest. I expect certain calls to a mocked function (`EXPECT_CALL(*rtosMock, xQueueGenericSend( arg , _, _, _)).Times(AtLeast(1));`) with some different values for `arg`. I end up receiving an call with an unexpected value.

```
unknown file: Failure

Unexpected mock function call - returning default value.
      Function call: xQueueGenericSend(NULL, 0x7fff38c99e80, 100, 0)
           Returns: 0
Google Mock tried the following 24 expectations, but none matched:

test.cpp:95: tried expectation #0: EXPECT_CALL(*rtosMock, xQueueGenericSend( arg , _, _, _))...
Expected arg #0: is equal to 0x561fede86f74
Actual: NULL
Expected: to be called at least once
Actual: called twice - satisfied and active
[...]
```

In the console it now show me which values it expected and the one which didn't fit, but not where the unexpected call was made. Is there a way to get to know where the unexpected call came from (like printing a file, line number or the callstack), other then stepping through the program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From documentation: https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/docs/gmock_faq.md#i-cant-figure-out-why-gmock-thinks-my-expectations-are-not-satisfied-what-should-i-do

If you run your test program with `--gmock_verbose=info`, GoogleMock will print stack trace after each call to mock method. This may result is a huge output however, especially with large tests. You may want to limit your tests to the particular one (i.e. the failing one) with `--gtest_filter=` flag or set environment variable GTEST_FILTER. It uses a regex of tests you want to run.

You can also run your code in the debugger and set breakpoint on a call of the `xQueueGenericSend`, and check each and every call to see when the failure occurs. You will be then able to narrow down possible places of bug occurence.

Comment: It just seems to ignore the `--gmock_verbose=info` flag, when I am passing it to the binary. Executing with `--help` lists also only `googletest` and no `googlemock` options. Do I have to enable args 2 `gmock` somwhere in my program or when building the test libraries?

Comment: I only had `::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);` in my main, and  `::testing::InitGoogleMock(&argc, argv);` was missing. Adding the mock initialization made your proposal work. Thanks a lot!